# how change sidebar menu depending on top navbar selection in mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I created partial view with top navbar in mvc using some bootstrap like below (_layout.cshtml) and it works but I'd like to switch to different sidebar on each topbar nav selection. How to do this? where to switch sidemenu? Should I have separate partial view for each sidemenu? if yes how to change them in main _layout view?
thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("SideMenuA", "sm1", "top")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("SideMenuB", "sm2", "top")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("SideMenuC", "sm3", "top")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="nav  navbar-fixed-side navbar-fixed-side-left">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("A", "A", "side")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("B", "B", "side")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("C", "C", "side")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create separate side menu partial views.
And define a `section` for side menu in the `Layout.cshtml`..

```
  <div class="col-md-2 column-divider">
      @RenderSection("Sidemenu", required: false)
  </div>
```

Then, In each of your views (for example in `Index.cshtml`), add a `Sidemenu section` so that it outputs `_Sidemenu` partial view..

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Title";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

@section Sidemenu
{
   @Html.Partial("_Sidemenu") // side menu partial specific to this view
}
```

You can read [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor) for detail.